# Copy/Paste image Element in ArcPy 10.3

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, image, copy, paste

I seeking a way to copy/paste an image in the layout with python code.

I saw this documentation: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/pictureelement-class.htm but didn't found any hint there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone [TextElement](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/textelement-class.htm) and [GraphicElement](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/graphicelement-class.htm) objects but there is no `clone` method for the [PictureElement](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/pictureelement-class.htm) class.

There does not seem to be an existing ArcGIS Idea to have one implemented in either ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro.  If you want that to happen you could submit one at [ArcGIS Ideas](https://community.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas) and, if you do, I suggest that you target ArcGIS Pro rather than ArcMap because I think that is where all current desktop GIS development is going.